# A problem in Graph theory $e\le 5/3 v-10/3$

Tags: graph-theory

I am having the problem in the following question:

> Suppose $G$ is a connected simple planar graph with $e$ edges and $v$ vertices with no cycles of length 4 or less. Then prove that $$ e\le \frac{5}{3}v-\frac{10}{3},\ \ \text{for }v\ge 4 $$

I know the following result  Let $G$ be a connected planar simple graph with $v$ vertices, where $v \ge 3$ and $e$ edges. Then $e \le 3v - 6$.

But I am unable to do the above. So could you please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Redo the same proof as the one for $e \leq 3v-6$:

By Euler
$$v-e+f=2$$

Now, if there are no cycles, $f=1$ and prove the result.

If there are cycles, count the edges by faces. Since each face has at least 5 edges, your count is at least $5f$. Since you count each edge exactly twice, your count is exactly $2e$.

This shows that 
$$2e \geq 5f$$

Combine this with Euler formula and you are done